# Overwriting an object closes the DB connection?

Tags: php, database-connection

We're getting an error from the server saying that there are to many DB connection to the DB. I'm trying to locate the logic which causes the lack of optimization. We connect to the DB using an object called `DB_Con`. This object creates the connection on init.

My question is if 
    `$Con = new DB_Con`
would 
    `$Con = null`
close the connection? If so is it done right away or is it slated for garbage collection at a later time.

Also, would the following two lines of code open two DB connections or one?

```
$Con = new DB_Con 
$Con = new DB_Con
```

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors: how is `DB_Con` storing the connection itself? (is it using PDO? mysqli? old out dated mysql extension?) Are you using persistent connections? We need more information about the internals of `DB_Con` to effectively answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only really have 1 DB Connection open per execution.

When you're done with the DB use [$mysqli->close();](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)

It's even noted on the close page that unless you explicitly close a connection the connection will not close.

Comment: Could you clarify for I found this and it seems to contradict your last statement. Also we're using PDO if it makes a difference.  "
Upon successful connection to the database, an instance of the PDO class is returned to your script. The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object. To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends."

Comment: My comment was for an mysqli implementation.

In the notes section here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php it mentions "Starting with PHP 5.4 you are unable to use persistent connections when you have your own database class derived from the native PDO class."  As for specifics with PDO sorry I don't use it.  There may be a lot of unique conditions with different database extensions.